# Text ellipsizing from middle even if it is set to END in android

Tags: android

I am setting textview maxline, ellipsize and maxwidth property dynamically :-

```
textView.setMaxLines(2);
textView.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.END);
text.setMaxWidth(500);
```

but the text is getting ellipsized from middle and from end too :-

"ewfejfkdefiuehfkjoenrfjnerhijfengbhnr hbeijkfnhriue neiufneir nbifejknjivc jhinevjni efgrekjn elkrmnlkelkel melelerkmg emlkemg lkjen wken... eghijengiuerm iuenvo jheoivjn ervn eioveo..."

I don't know the error here as i am doing nothing wrong here.

Comment: I just tried it myself...I'm getting correct result. Clean your project and then run the project...may be it will do something.

Comment: It is happening on some devices with long text like nexus 7 and samsung 10 inch tablet and i am not even setting ems.